# Datedim function not returning yesterdays date webi

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, webi

My Datedim function is not returning yesterdays date in webi, any ideas on how to show 13/04/2022, even if it has null values?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have gaps in your date data the simplest way to fill them in is to create a variable with the [TimeDim()](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_BUSINESSOBJECTS_BUSINESS_INTELLIGENCE_PLATFORM/987ff4008e2d47fb9f92f7b085a204cd/4718f3d86e041014910aba7db0e91070.html?version=4.2.9) function. However, that will not work for you since you do not have a true gap because your missing date is at the end.

You need a data source with all the dates you want to display regardless of if you have data for those dates or not and then merge on your date dimension. I answered a question very similar to this [here](https://bobj-board.org/t/text-fields-missing/257745/8). I am copying my answer from there below...

> The TimeDim() function will fill in the empty periods in your time
> data. The problem with that though is if it is the end of your date
> range that is missing data those dates will not show up. Let me show
> you what I mean. Here is my sample data from 12/01/2021 through
> 12/26/2021 (note missing dates) in the table on the left. The table on
> the right is the my **Var Data Date TimeDim** variable defined as…
>
> ```
> =TimeDim([Data Date]; DayPeriod)
> ```
>
> [image: Missing Data]
>
> So we have our missing dates in the middle, but not at the end
> (12/25/2021 and 12/26/2021). To get those dates you need a query to
> return all the dates in your specified range. If you have a [universe
> based on a
> calendar](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/11/first-day-of-previous-week-with-a-twist/)
> you could use that. Free-hand SQL based on a calendar table would
> suffice as well.
>
> If you have neither of those we can still get it to work using
> free-hand SQL with a CTE. This is SQL Server syntax. You will have to
> modify this SQL to work for whatever database platform you have if it
> isn’t SQL Server.
>
> Here is the SQL…
>
> ```
> ;with dates ([Date]) as (
> Select convert(date,‘2021-12-01’) as [Date] – Put the start date here
>
> union all
>
> Select dateadd(day, 1, [Date])
> from dates
> where [Date] < ‘2021-12-26’ – Put the end date here
> )
>
> select [Date]
> from dates
> option (maxrecursion 32767) – Don’t forget to use the maxrecursion option!
> ```
>
> Source: [Generate a Date Table via Common Table Expression (CTE) |
> Data and Analytics with Dustin
> Ryan](https://sqldusty.com/2015/05/15/generate-a-date-table-via-common-table-expression-cte/)
>
> Here is a
> [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04805ca4ac56623ce3b8158738dc05d2).
>
> Now that you have a query returning **all** of the dates in your range
> you can merge the date from that query to your **Data Date**.
>
> You can then put the date object with all of dates or the Merged Date
> in table with any measures from your pre-existing query and there you
> have it.
>
> [image: Missing Data 2]
>
> If you need to add dimensions from you pre-existing query I think you
> will need to create variables for them with **Qualification** set to
> “Detail” and the **Associated dimension** set to “Merged Date” (or
> whatever you called it). And if you do that I believe you will also
> need to check “Avoid duplicate row aggregation” check box within the
> Format Table properties.
>
> [image: Missing Data 3]
>
> Let us know how it goes.

Hopefully that will get you on the right track.